# Replace/append substring with sed

Tags: linux, sed

I would like to ask your help!

The problem is:

I have a code:
`<h1....>text</h1>`

I would like to make a result:
`<h1 ....><a name="Snumber">text</a></h1>` where S is character, number is a variable integer.

My problem that I don't know, how to subs non-fix  at the beginning of the line, how could I use regular expression for it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can forward you to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags which is quite interesting topic and will give you a good overview.

Comment: What are S and number going to be determined by? Something internal to the string or are you calling this in a loop or what?

Comment: What is S and number? A result must be in S1, S2, S3 etc. but it is not a problem.:-)

Comment: If I try another example: I would like to take this: every word with beginning asa change asa*newchars, where * is a second part of original string.

Comment: If you think awk is better for this, it is no problem!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your requirement clearly something like that will work for you in bash:

```
str='<h1 class="a">text</h1>' # this is your original string
ch='S' # this is your character
n='56789' # this is your number
echo "${str}<${ch}${n}>" | \
  sed 's#\(<h1[^>]*>\)\([^<]*\)\(</h1>\)<\([^>]*\)>#\1<a name="\4">\2</a>\3#'

OUTPUT:
<h1 class="a"><a name="G56789">text</a></h1>
```

Sorry if there is any misunderstanding on my part then I will happily delete my answer.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your help. The problem is that I read it from file, where your str is variable:-( The simpler is <h1>, there is no problem. But sometimes is <h1 class="something"> or any other strings after <h1 ....>  So I need to replace <h1 ....> to <h1 ....><a name="S"> Is it clear?

Comment: @Peter: If you see my answer it takes care of all `<h1...>` not just `<h1>`. Even my example has `<h1 class="a">text</h1>`. Of course this string can be read from file as well in bash.